# Exit from script by running another script instead

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this conditional in a script:

```
if [[ "${SUMAN_ENV}" != "local" ]]; then
 ./suman.sh $@  # run this script instead
 # need to exit here
fi
```

if the condition is met, I'd like to run another script instead.

Is the best way to do this just to do this:

```
if [[ "${SUMAN_ENV}" != "local" ]]; then
 ./suman.sh $@
 exit $?  # exit with the code given by the above command
fi
```

or is there some other way?

Comment: Note: You want to use `"$@"` with quotes to handle arguments with whitespace correctly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

File `hello`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$0"
exec ./world
echo "$0"
```

File `world`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$0"
exit 33 # to have an exit code example
```

Run `hello`:

```
$ ./hello 
./hello
./world
$ echo $?
33
```

After `hello` runs `world` via `exec` and `world` finishes, the remainder of `hello` is not executed. The exit code is the one of `world`.

Comment: `exec` replaces the currently running process with the one specified. The PID is unchanged.

Most of the resources for the original process are released.

Comment: @yeti what is `exit 33` ? Isn't `exit` enough ?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut ... `exit` would have been enough but in the question's snippets the 1st script explicitely exits with the exit value of the called 2nd script. So I wanted the 2nd one in my example have a different `exit` value than the 1st one to have distinguishable values. (No purple magic included there. No explicit `exit` would be ok too...)

Comment: So using `exec` is the key thing here I guess.

Comment: So using exec is the key thing here I guess???